# Powershell : Match file name with folder name

Tags: powershell, directory, filenames

I'm trying to match file name with folder name before move them to an other directory.

For example, my script need to match if "Test.txt" match with a folder named "Test" and move them to a different directory.

Is it possible with the cmdlets Get-ChildItem ? I didn't find any examples :(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` enables you to list (recursively or not) the content of a specified directory. Then you can check if a directory with the name of your file exists. (`Get-Help Test-Path`should help a bit)

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell 3+

Gets all files recursively from the current directory whose names (without extension) matches its directory's name:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -eq $_.Directory.Name }
```

### PowerShell 1, 2

There is no `-File` switch until PowerShell 3, so you have to filter out directories with an extra `Where-Object`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -eq $_.Directory.Name }
```

Once you've got all the files that match their parent directory name, you should be able to move them. I'm not sure what your logic is for the destination directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can use the `Directory` property of `Get-ChildItem`

So lets say you are looking for a file `test.txt` but only if it is in the directory `Scripts`

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -recurse | Where-Object{($_.Name -eq "test.txt") -and ($_.Directory -like "*\scripts")} | Move-Item $_.Directory "C:\NewFolder"
```

The `Where` clause will look for a file called `text.txt` as long as its in a folder called `c:\somepath\scripts`. So this will not match `c:\anotherpath\test.txt`. When a match is found Move the located `files` directory to a new location.

**Note** I am not sure if the logic will hold if multiple file matches are found. If it fails then we could assign all the matches to a variable and then process the all the unique values.

```
$foundDirectories = Get-ChildItem *.txt -recurse | Where-Object{($_.Name -eq "test.txt") -and ($_.Directory -like "*\scripts")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory -Unique
$foundDirectories | ForEach-Object{Move-Item $_ "C:\newfolder"}
```